# Bendy Bones alternative

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

Bendy Bones is an impressive tool but i can't export it to UE4.
Do you have any alternative way ? If you have it, can you explain me ?

[image]

Thanks !

---

Here's my file.

[Link - File address](https://mega.nz/#!f7QHXBhR!TffM-TCoqBjfISi6TvzhedDlJBjVgPPeQaX-d5OA8Yo)

I tried something like this but the Beziercurve doesn't follow in pose mode.

PS: i would like to create an animation and then export it to UE4.

Thanks !

Comment: You could just use a normal curve, change it into a mesh, and then export it?

Comment: Anything you can do with bendy bones, you can do with spline IK.  It's just more painful to set up and use.  By a lot, IMO.  Take a look for info on spline IK and how to use hooks on curves.  (And drivers, if you need Y axis rotation.)

Answer (score 2):

Use Spline IK instead.

Here's some documentations for you to explore:

- [*Spline IK* - Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/spline_ik.html)
- [*Creating an IK and Spline IK switch in blender for beginers ans advance* by the luwizart Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHn51y2qBV4)
- [Spline IK - Unreal Engine Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Animation/NodeReference/SkeletalControls/SplineIK)

More tricky to setup, but does the job quite right.
Have fun with that.